# Dynamic backgroundColor in SafeAreaView react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, safeareaview, react-safeareaview

I am using `SafeAreaView` provided by `react-navigation` and inside that, I am having my navigation controller.

What I want is the dynamic color for header i.e. notch in `iOS` and `android`. I want different notch background for different screens.

This is how i have used SafeAreaView

```
<SafeAreaView
    style={{flex:1}
    forceInset={{ bottom: 'always', top: 'always' }}>
    <Root>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <ReduxNavigation />
    </Root>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this?